# Positioning help-tip box in the correct place with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to correctly adjust the position of the help-tip box so it always shows like this:

[image: Position I want]

I mean, with the pointer just in the "Help circle". But I'm having problems with configuring it. Vertically it's already OK, but I am not being able to adjust it horizontally. **Here I leave the JS Fiddle URL:**

https://jsfiddle.net/28dsnmxs/2/

As you can see there, the help-tip box is totally messed up, not where it should be. I want to correct that.

```css
.help-tip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #BCDBEA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: default;
}
.help-tip:before {
  content: '?';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
.help-tip:hover p {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.help-tip p {
  /* The tooltip */
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #1E2021;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.help-tip p:before {
  /* The pointer of the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #1E2021;
  right: 63px;
  top: -12px;
}
.help-tip p:after {
  /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
}
/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="help-tip">
  <p>Formato: nombre@dominio.com</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `position:relative` on parent, and use `right` coordonates to set the arrow where you want.

remove also  `overflow` from the form.

https://jsfiddle.net/28dsnmxs/4/

```css
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-family: Tahoma;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

body{
 background-color: #E0ECF8;
}

section#formulario{/* removed overflow:hidden */
 width:400px;
 min-height: 100px;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}

section#formulariorespuestas{
 width:600px;
 min-height: 100px;
 background-color: white;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 20px; 
}

p#titulo{
 font-size: 1.6em;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p#dato{
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-left: 40px;
 }

p#opcionesenvio{
 font-size: 1.6em;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

p#questions{
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 text-align: left;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="mail"], input[type="birth"], input[type="dni"]{
 width: 335px;
 height: 35px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top:10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 outline: none;
 border:0px;
 background-color: #dcdcdc;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

textarea{
 width: 335px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top:10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 font-size: 1em;
 outline: none;
 border:0px;
 background-color: #dcdcdc;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#outer
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner
{
    display: inline-block;
}


input[type="submit"]{
 margin:20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width:157px;
 height: 40px;
 outline: none;
 border:0px;
 background-color: #75b6dc;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 5px 0px #659dbf;

}

input[type="reset"]{
 margin:20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width:157px;
 height: 40px;
 outline: none;
 border:0px;
 background-color: #585858;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 5px 0px #424242;

}

span.negrita{
 font-weight: bold;
}

.help-tip{
  position:relative;/* added instead static */
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #BCDBEA;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 26px;
 cursor: default;
} 

.help-tip:before{
 content:'?'; 
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
 display:block;
 transform-origin: 100% 0%;

 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
 animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{ /* The tooltip */
 display: none;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #1E2021;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
  z-index:1;/* added */
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.4;
  right:-58px;/* added */
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 width:0;
 height: 0;
 border:6px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
 right:63px;
 top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 content:'';
 position: absolute;
 top:-40px;
 left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
 0% { 
  opacity:0; 
  transform: scale(0.6);
 }

 100% {
  opacity:100%;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0% { opacity:0; }
 100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Formulario de registro</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="p1.css">
<script type="text/javaScript" src="p1.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
 <section id="formulario">
  <p id="titulo">Formulario de registro</p>

  <form method="POST" action="" name="formulario" id="form" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
   <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
   <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">
   <input type="text" id="birth" name="birth" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento">
   <div class="help-tip"><p>Formato: DD/MM/YYYY</p></div>
   <input type="text" id="dni" name="dni" placeholder="DNI">
   <div class="help-tip"><p>Formato ejemplo: 99999999L</p></div>
   <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Tel&eacute;fono">
   <div class="help-tip"><p>Formato ejemplo: 887889781</p></div>
   <input type="mail" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Correo electr&oacute;nico">
   <div class="help-tip"><p>Formato: nombre@dominio.com</p></div>
   <input type="password" id="pass" name="pwd1" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a">
   <div class="help-tip"><p>Mínimo 6 caracteres. Debe contener al menos una letra mayúscula y un número.</p></div>
   <input type="password" id="pass" name="pwd2" placeholder="Confirmar contrase&ntilde;a">
   <p id="questions">¿Cuáles fueron sus estudios anteriores?<br>
   <select name="studieslist" form="form">
    <option value="bach">Bachillerato</option>
    <option value="ciclo">Ciclo Superior</option>
    <option value="extra">Estudios en el extranjero</option>
   </select>
   <p id="questions">¿Desea recibir comunicaciones por parte de la Universidad de Vigo?<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="1" id="g"> SMS
   <br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="2" id="g"> Correo electrónico
   <br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value="3" id="g"> Teléfono
   <br/>
   <input type="button" id="prueba" name="sub" value="Marcar todas" onclick="checkall(document.formulario.h)">
   <input type="button" name="sub" value="Desmarcar todas" onclick="uncheckall(document.formulario.h)">
   <p id="questions">¿Desea activar el servicio de "Notas al móvil"?<br>
   <input type="radio" name="mobilegrade" value="yes" checked="checked"> Sí<br>
   <input type="radio" name="mobilegrade" value="no"> No</p>
   <p id="questions">Escriba aquí cualquier información adicional que desee adjuntar con el formulario:<br>
   <textarea name="comment" form="form" placeholder="Información adicional..." rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></p>
   <div id="outer">
   <p id="opcionesenvio">Opciones de envío</p>
   <p id="questions">Tipo de codificación:<br>
   <input type="radio" name="codification" value="urlencoded" checked="checked"> application/x-www-form-urlencoded<br>
   <input type="radio" name="codification" value="multipart"> multipart/form-data</p>
   <p id="questions">Método de envío:<br>
   <input type="radio" name="sendmethod" value="GET"> GET<br>
   <input type="radio" name="sendmethod" value="POST" checked="checked"> POST</p>
   <p id="questions">Enviar a:<br>
   <input type="radio" name="sendto" value="myphp" checked="checked"> Fichero PHP (p1.php)<br>
   <input type="radio" name="sendto" value="sintprofphp"> URL "/~sint0/p1.php"</p>
   <input type="hidden" name="navegador"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="hora"/>
   <div class="inner"><input type="submit" value="enviar"></div>
   <div class="inner"><input type="reset" value="limpiar"></div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

to fix it with simple css, plz see below css changes  OR Fiddle -

```
section#formulario {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    /* overflow: hidden; */  /* removed */
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.help-tip {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; /* modified */
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip p {
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 25px;     /* added */
    right: -57px;  /* added */
    z-index: 999;  /* added */
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

fiddle -

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/u5r9xrbd/
```